# Traverse all outgoing relationships in neo4j rest api

Tags: rest, traversal, neo4j, relationships

I want to traverse all nodes with "all" outgoing relationships.
But all examples I can find use the direction only in combination with the relationship type.

`{...
  "relationships" : [ {
    "direction" : "all",
    "type" : "knows"
  }, {
    "direction" : "all",
    "type" : "loves"
  } ]
  ...
}`

I still tried to use `"relationships" : "out"` but I get an error 500 "cannot cast String to Map".
Only giving an array with a direction doesn't work and throws an error 500 "type cannot be null".

Is it possible to don't specify all types of relations with direction "out"?

Comment: I have faced the same issue. Can you share your server plugin?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the code anymore. In 2011 we evaluated some NoSQL databases for our company needs and dropped neo4j.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. It's definitely something to add in future versions! In the mean time you could write your own plugin to do that, like: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html

Comment: I realized it with a server plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

created a ticket for this, see https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/6

Is this correct?